# Adapting a gamebook to multiple players

Tags: game-design, group-scaling, freeform

This is my first question, so I am truly sorry if it is nonsense.
I am a newbie to RPG, however, I used to play gamebooks (Fighting Fantasy) and I really enjoyed them.

I want to test if my group of friends would like to play RPG, but I don't have time to learn a real system, and I don't know if they would enjoy it.

Thus, I am adapting a gamebook for us to play.
Of course, I will develop the story, creating new characters, monsters, to give them more options similar to a true RPG. But I will keep the mechanics very simple.

Doing this, I encountered a problem.

In the gamebook, there is an attribute called faith. You get your faith level by rolling a dice and adding 1 to the result. A faith test is when you play 2 dice, add a modifier to the result (as it may be a hard test), and if the result is lower or equal to the player's faith level, they passed it.  Otherwise, they fail it.

I don't know how I could adapt these faith-tests to multiple players.

Let's suppose a situation where if the single player has success in the faith test and sees a ghost that chats with him.

How could I adapt faith-tests to about 2-3 players, as most of the time their characters will be together?

My aim is it to keep faith-tests mechanically-balanced:

I thought about each player doing the test, and if at least one player passes the test, then the ghost would show. But I don't think that would be good, as it would be easier for the group to pass the faith tests than it would be for a sole player.

I'm sorry for my bad English, it is not my mother tongue.

Comment: Welcome! You can take the [tour] as an introduction to the site and check the [help] for further guidance. I am afraid this question may not be suited to our format as it seems to be mostly asking for idea generation. I recommend you check our [list of forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/33707) where you may be able to find what you need. Good luck and gaming!

Comment: Thank you so much, I will surely take a look at it. I am sorry if is not suited here, feel free to delete it if needed.

Comment: In this instance I am honestly not sure myself and you may be able to change the question a bit, making it better suit our format. Note that that previous comment was my opinion on the matter and others may disagree. I do think it can't hurt to check some of those forums regardless.

Comment: @Sdjz this seems suited as this is about balancing game-mechanics, but it requires specific expertise to answer.

Comment: Your English is fine, I just made a few edits to get the prose to flow a little better.

Comment: I suspect you're underestimating the vastness of the [RPG landscape](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1475/8610) when you write that you "don't have time to learn a real system." [There are playable RPGs that are literally only 200 words.](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8252/8610) Consider asking for suggestions for a dead-easy actual system on one of [these forums.](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/8610) And, sincerely, thank you—and your friends!—for taking an interest in the hobby!

Comment: For your case [Advanced Fighting Fantasy](http://www.arion-games.com/aff.html) was invented for!